# Request GZipped content in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, httpwebrequest

I'm having trouble to request Gzipped content with Silverlight 5. To reduce used bandwidth I want to use gzip for the content that's requested from our webservice, but unfortunately this does not work.

I'm using the Client Stack and send a HttpWebRequest. I tried to set the Accept-Encoding header, but it tells me that I'm not allowed to change this directly - and there's no other property for it!

So how can I send a custom Accept-Encoding header?

This is the code I have in my App-Constructor:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

This is how I create the request and set the header:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
webRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
```

This is the exception:

```
{System.ArgumentException: The 'Accept-Encoding' header cannot be modified directly.
Parameter name: name
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyClass}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate answer is: don't use the client stack if you want to gzip (the browser stack handles this for you already)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm fortunate enough to control the service side as well as the client side. What I have done now is adding an additional custom header that will essentially override the Accept-Encoding header. I call it "Accept-Encoding-Override". When my service encounters this header it'll compress the the content no matter what's in the Accept-Encoding header. On the client silverlight side I check the Content-Encoding header in the response and if necessary unzip it using SharpZipLib (DotNetZip did not work).

I still mark dotMorten as his response is the actually answer to my question. There's no way to set the header when using ClientStack.

Comment: Just to note: I have a library for WP7/WP8 that makes the processing of these requests A LOT easier. It should be a simple matter of compiling it for Silverlight and changed the header and Content-Encoding check to your custom one and you should be good to go with a minimum of extra code. See here: https://github.com/dotMorten/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient/

Comment: I found your library during my research, and it may be useful for others but for me it has no use. :) I already have a working infrastructure, and all I had to do on the client side is additionally send my custom header and in my parsing method inject a GZipStream, but only if the Content-Encoding is gzip. This way my code will still work when the response is not the expected gzip.

Comment: ?? My code doesn't unzip if the response isn't gzipped. You can write just two lines of code in the app startup by calling RegisterPrefix and ALL web requests throughout the app  will now attempt to get gzip if possible (you can also do it per request with the GZipWebClient though)